# Wrapping one's head around priority arguments

Tags: proof-techniques

One of my undergraduate math professors used to say "we'll always be drawing a picture, even when it is impossible", and I came to strongly sympathize with his witty point.  Some recursion theory proof techniques are rather easy to visualize: diagonalization argument is easily pictured as filling out a table, and subsequently flipping ones and zeros on the diagonal. Priority arguments feel very different and seem hard to visualize. Realizing this may be more of a psychology than a math question, is there some suitable way to "picture" priority arguments? Is there (or need there be?) some sort of a visual way of dealing with complicated (priority) proofs for those proofs to be properly understood?

For example: The proof of Friedberg-Muchnik theorem, or, as a simpler example, Post's construction of a simple set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture for you: Your requirements are ordered as $0,1,2,\ldots$; each requirement equipped with a lamp that can be grey, green or red. Initially, all requirements are grey, as they are not active yet. If a requirement becomes active, the light turns red. Your construction provides a way to handle each individual requirement, doing so turns its light green. However, handling a requirement can mess with other requirements of higher numbers, turning them grey or red again, even if they were already green.

The overarching structure of a priority argument states that for any set of requirements that will eventually become active, the process ensures that in the limit, no lights are red.